# Populate a combobox with array information

Tags: c#, arrays, combobox

I'm trying to populate a `ComboBox` with PART of an array that is in another class. I have to make an application that creates customers, inventory and orders. On the order form, I'm trying to pull the customer ID and inventory ID information from the arrays that are in the customer and inventory classes respectively. The arrays have multiple types of information in them: Customer ID, name, Address, state, zip, etc; Inventory ID, Name, discount value and price.

This is what my arrays are set up like:

```
public static Customer[] myCustArray = new Customer[100];

public string customerID;
public string customerName;
public string customerAddress;
public string customerState;
public int customerZip;
public int customerAge;
public int totalOrdered;
```

and this is what my comboboxes are sort of set up like:

```
public void custIDComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    custIDComboBox.Items.AddRange(Customer.myCustArray);

    custIDComboBox.DataSource = Customer.getAllCustomers();
}
```

Comment: could you show us the code?

Comment: Do you want the values from the two different arrays go into the same ComboBox or different ones?  Also, is this for ASP.Net, WPF, or WinForms?

Comment: @mahditahsildari I don't know what parts are completely relevant. I have my arrays set up like above. I'm trying to get to the customerID string element in the array when the customers are input.

Comment: @MauriceReeves two separate combo boxes. And I believe WinForms. I'm using Visual Studio for a class.

Comment: Excellent, then follow @Mortalus' example below.  He's got you covered.

Comment: @user1911789 do you want to have both `Value Member` and `Display Member` or just showing items are enough?

Answer (score 5):

Use data binding.

Giving an existing array of object (in your case "Customers") defined as such:

```
public static Customer[] myCustArray = new Customer[100];
```

Define the array as the data source like this:

```
BindingSource theBindingSource = new BindingSource();
theBindingSource.DataSource = myCustArray;
myComboBox.DataSource = bindingSource.DataSource;
```

Then you can set the lable and value of each item like this:

```
//That should be a string represeting the name of the customer object property.
myComboBox.DisplayMember = "customerName";
myComboBox.ValueMember = "customerID";
```

And that's it.

Comment: What system do you have to call to use the DataLabel and DataValue methods?

Comment: I had a mistake, the properties of the combobox are `DataValueField` and `DataTextField` and you should use `System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList`

Comment: @Mortalus this is not a web application

Comment: I'm not able to add System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList.

Comment: @user1911789 because you are not working on a web based project, you are working on a windows based application. This behavior is web's

Comment: Does that mean I cannot use the databind methods? That's a shame, that looks much simpler than anything I was trying to do!

Comment: You can it's the same use 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' i'll chage the example to fit in a few seconds..

Comment: See Edits Made for Win Forms sorry i have missed the TAG and thought you were talking about ASP.NET

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't allow me to run the code with the BindingSource.DataSource = myCustArray line. Basically, intellisense doesn't allow DataSource to be selected by BindingSource.

Comment: What do you mean doesn't allow ? do you get a compiler error when you write the code i gave you if so what error d you get ? NOTE that you do not assign `MyCustArray` to the data source you assign `bindingSource.Datasource` object that contained a reference to `MyCustArray`

Answer (score 1):

```
Customer.myCustArray[0] = new Customer { customerID = "1", customerName = "Jane" };  
Customer.myCustArray[1] = new Customer { customerID = "2", customerName = "Jack" };
```

you won't need two lines above, I added them to see the output, the following code generates the ComboBox items:

```
foreach (Customer cus in Customer.myCustArray)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add("[" + cus.customerID + "] " + cus.customerName);
}
```

you can copy this code to the appropriate event, for example it can be `FormLoad`, and if you want your ComboBox's items refresh every time  your form activates you can do this:

```
private void Form3_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Clear();
    foreach (Customer cus in Customer.myCustArray)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add("[" + cus.customerID + "] " + cus.customerName);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I have a separate form to add customers via text boxes. The names and everything else are stored in an array like above.

Comment: I already have the array, I just need to access the index [0] (which I have set up as customer ID) for all customers and display it to a combo box on a separate form.

Comment: Then just use this code 
    for (int i = 0; i < myCustomer.Count(); i++)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(myCustomer[i].Fname);
    }

Comment: @kovilpattiCsharper I have my arrays set up like I put in the initial question. How would I call the ID specifically with the array created like that?

Comment: @mahditahsildari what method would I put this in?

Comment: @user1911789 depends. put it where you want your combo box to be filled, Form load can be a good option

Comment: if your data may change while your form is open you can also put the code in `FormActivated` event, I tested it and it works fine.